# XPages: sending mail to a mailing list

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I am trying to send a mail to a large number of client with my XPages application, the application is supposed to create an save an email document then send out the mail to a specific mailing list.

but after sending 10 to 15mails the browser get a timeout and is end the process.

is there any workaround for this or is there any way to make it run on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decouple the browser response from the email sending process.

I would create a bean in an application context. Inside the bean a Java thread to run in the background for mail sending and return the browser in the front thread. 
If you want to keep the UI updated you could use a web socket connection.

Use this for more information: http://www.intec.co.uk/xots-background-and-multithreaded-tasks-the-openntf-domino-api-way-part-one/

Comment: Do you a sample nsf that could send mail or do a server-side job using Java thread?

Comment: When you use a Java thread you need to make sure the bean lives long enough - so application context would be safest. Just make sure users don’t overwrite each other. Or follow Paul’s advice with xots in the link. Depends on how many you send

Answer (score 1):

Stephan Wissel (stwissel) has given you the best answer. But until you have implemented that, you can use the following to increase the time until timeout:

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
        XSP.addOnLoad(function(){
            XSP.submitLatency = 1000*1000;
        });
    ]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

`XSP.submitLatency` is measured in milliseconds.